# NSTableView and data validation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

In order to properly learn Objective-C and the Cocoa framework, I have started building a CoreData application, but I'm a bit at a loss on how to properly provide data validation when an item is being edited in an NSTableView.

My model has an entity called "Business" with two string properties: a name and an issued tax number. The second property must have a length of exactly 10 characters. This entity's objects are displayed and edited in an NSTableView, through an NSArrayController bound to the Business entity and the app's managedObjectContext.

What I would like to do is:
- the user starts editing the tax number in the appropriate cell (NSTextFieldCell) of the tableview.
- when pressing Enter, the new value is validated, i.e. checks to see that the new value has a length of 10 characters. If validation fails, an alert sounds and the cell keeps being focused.
- pressing Escape restores the old value and the cell loses focus.

What is the proper way to perform this validation?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Managed Object Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html) chapter of the Core Data Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bindings, you can check the "Validates Immediately" in the binding for cell value. That will call the validation method for the managed object.